# SSAS Cube connection in Excel with Integrated Security will refresh only after Enable Content is clicked

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, pivot-table, olap-cube

We are trying to distribute a report in Excel that connects to a SSAS cube in a Pivot Table, the problem we are facing is about security. When saving the file, it will save a "snapshot" of the cube data that the creator is allowed to see. When another user opens the report, he can see all that data, only after she clicks on "Enable Content" will she get a refreshed pivot table with the appropriate data according to her security role. We're using authenticated security for the connection.

This is a big problem because they are not supposed to see, for example, profitability for other reporting units. Have you bumped into this? Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The problem sounds pretty familiar - but unfortunately I don't have "the" answer to it. What you might consider: Save the XLSX with as little data as possible / with a lower security user before sending it out. However, there is a good reason why Excel does not automatically refresh data: depending on the complexity of the query and the number of users who open the report at the same time, the AS Server might experience resource problems.

Comment: Indeed, I proceeded by creating a user with access to the cube but restricted all dimensions. I first created the "report" with my account, then I opened it under the fake user account and Enabled Content, the cube refreshed and the report looks empty but keeps all the format. That is the report we are sharing in the portal and when a regular user opens it, the cube will refresh and show the appropriate data.